# Парсер 1С Python

Tags: python, парсер, 1с

Когда пытаюсь парсить русские слова появляется эта ошибка.

return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 69: chara
cter maps to

Вот пример XML файла

```
            <Товар>
                <Ид>78f2974c-64af-11e8-b87d-902b34d405a5</Ид>
                <Штрихкод>11191108054</Штрихкод>
                <Артикул>1119-1108054</Артикул>
                <Наименование>Трос привода акселератора 1119 дв. 1.4</Наименование>
                <БазоваяЕдиница Код="796 " НаименованиеПолное="Штука" МеждународноеСокращение="PCE">
                    <Пересчет>
                        <Единица>796</Единица>
                        <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                    </Пересчет>
                </БазоваяЕдиница>
                <Группы>
                    <Ид>32ad98de-abd4-11e6-98fc-902b34d405a5</Ид>
                </Группы>
                <Описание>Димитровградский завод тросов привода «Автопартнер» — один из крупнейших в России производителей тросов и тяг привода для отечественных легковых и грузовых автомобилей. Наше предприятие является официальным поставщиком своей продукции на конвейеры всех российских автомобильных заводов, а также на вторичный рынок автозапчастей.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;

&lt;b&gt;Применяемость: &lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
LADA 1118, 1119.</Описание>
                <Изготовитель>
                    <Ид>7bf6ec72-304a-11ea-acd5-902b34d405a5</Ид>
                    <Наименование>Россия</Наименование>
                </Изготовитель>
                <ЗначенияСвойств>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>012ce100-2f89-11ea-82d5-8cdcd47af2ea</Ид>
                        <Значение>1119-1108054.</Значение>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>ba36fa01-0a42-11e3-9099-000fea3f9697</Ид>
                        <Значение>7bf6ec70-304a-11ea-acd5-902b34d405a5</Значение>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                </ЗначенияСвойств>
                <СтавкиНалогов>
                    <СтавкаНалога>
                        <Наименование>НДС</Наименование>
                        <Ставка>Без НДС</Ставка>
                    </СтавкаНалога>
                </СтавкиНалогов>
                <ЗначенияРеквизитов>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>Код</Наименование>
                        <Значение>УТ000002705</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>ВидНоменклатуры</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Товар</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>ТипНоменклатуры</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Товар</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>Полное наименование</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Трос привода акселератора 1119 дв. 1.4</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                </ЗначенияРеквизитов>
            </Товар>
```

Comment: Вдруг поможет - [Как прочитать html файл в Python?](https://qna.habr.com/q/223086)

Comment: Приведите пример кода, которым пытаетесь парсить файл